# PHP - Packing widgets into the fewest number of boxes, plus minimum order quantity

Tags: php, algorithm

The problem is this:

A company supplies widgets in a set of pack sizes:

- 250
- 500
- 1000
- 2000
- 5000

Customers can order any number of widgets, but the following rules apply:

- Only whole packs can be sent and …
- No more widgets than necessary should be sent and …
- The fewest packs possible should be sent

Some examples showing the number of widgets ordered and the required pack quantities and sizes to correctly fulfill the order:

- 1 (1 x 250)
- 251 (1 x 500)
- 501 (1 x 500 and 1 x 250)
- 12001 (2 x 5000 and 1 x 2000 and 1 x 250)

I’ve looked at some algorithms (greedy coin change, LAFF, etc.) as these seem to provide similar solutions. However, I'm ideally looking for a scalable, object oriented approach to solving this problem.

Here's what I've come up with so far:

```
<?php

function countWidgets($amount) 
{ 
    $packs = array(5000, 2000, 1000, 500, 
                  250); 
    $packCounter = array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0); 
    $packsCount = count($packs);

    // loop packs
    for ($i = 0; $i < $packsCount; $i++)  
    { 
        if ($amount >= $packs[$i]) 
        { 
            $packCounter[$i] = intval($amount /  
                                      $packs[$i]); 
            $amount = $amount -  
                      $packCounter[$i] *  
                      $packs[$i]; 
        } 
    }

    // if remainder
    if ($amount > 0) {
        // and if smallest pack size populated
        if ($packCounter[4] == 1) {
            // clear smallest pack size
            $packCounter[4] = 0;
            // increment next biggest pack size
            $packCounter[3] += 1;
        } else {
            // increment smallest pack size
            $packCounter[4] +=1;
        }
    }


    // Print packs 
    echo ("Pack ->"."\n"); 
    for ($i = 0; $i < $packsCount; $i++)  
    { 
        if ($packCounter[$i] != 0)  
        { 
            echo ($packs[$i] . " : " . 
                  $packCounter[$i] . "\n"); 
        } 
    } 
} 

$amount = 251; 
countWidgets($amount);
```

Comment: What is your question? Does what you have work?

Comment: If you want to use an object-oriented approach, why not go for it? The current code looks pretty raw for that. Additionally, if you have looked up existing algorithms already, what's the point in adding a new one?

Comment: Same question was asked yesterday here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/216702/php-packing-widgets-into-the-fewest-number-of-boxes-plus-minimum-order-quanti I do agree that SO is a better place for it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I agree that this is a bit harder than I assumed yesterday. You basically have two opposing demands:

1. No more widgets than necessary should be sent.
2. The fewest packs possible should be sent.

You **cannot** fulfill both. So if I tried to send 1200 widgets, rule 2 says I should send a pack of 2000, however, rule 1 says I should send 2 packs: one of 1000 and one of 250. Which rule should prevail?

I chose that rule 1 should prevail in the solution below. The reason is that no customer wants more widgets than absolutely necessary.

```
$packSizes = [ 250,
               500,
              1000,
              2000,
              5000];

function optimizePacks($packSizes,$number)
{
    rsort($packSizes);
    $requiredPacks = array_fill_keys($packSizes,0);
    foreach ($packSizes as $size) {
        $packs = floor($number/$size);
        if ($packs > 0) {
            $requiredPacks[$size] = $packs;
            $number -= $packs*$size;
        }
    }
    if ($number > 0) $requiredPacks[min($packSizes)]++;
    return $requiredPacks;
}

$packs = optimizePacks($packSizes,6666);

print_r($packs);
```

This will work for any array of pack sizes and any number of widgets. The output of this code is:

> Array (
>       [5000] => 1
>       [2000] => 0
>       [1000] => 1
>       [500] => 1
>       [250] => 1 )

Which is one pack more than rule 2 would demand (one of 5000 and two of 1000). It would, of course, be possible to let rule 2 prevail, but I cannot fulfill both rules.